# How to know in which geofence am I?

Tags: android, android-geofence

I'm using geofencing with Android.
I have created the geofencing and I received when I enter or exit from a geofence. No problem.
But I want to know if exists a method to know in which geonfences am I in a moment, without save all the transitions manually.

Thank you!

Comment: Check also the GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL transition type.

Comment: Thank you, I solve it controlling the enters and exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it is not possible and you have to save the transitions.